# chrome layout only correct after window resize

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, layout

I'm having a strange issue with chrome where the initial rendering of the page is incorrect, but as soon anything is done that forces a redraw (eg. resizing the window) then the layout is rendered correctly. Maximizing also seems to cause problems.

[codepen example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOWQBE)

Initial (bad) layout:[image: initial (bad) layout]
Redrawn (good) layout[image: Redrawn (good) layout]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.photo-frame {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.75%;
  background-color: #111;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.photo-matte {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5% 6%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 12px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.photo-inset {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  border-top-color: rgba(170, 170, 170, 1.0);
  border-right-color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 1.0);
  border-bottom-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1.0);
  border-left-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1.0);
}
img {
  height: 70vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="photo-frame">
    <div class="photo-matte">
      <div class="photo-inset">
        <img src="http://jlee.me/glow_cube.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: after some more tinkering, this only seems to fail when the CSS height for the  is specified.

Comment: Seems exactly the same to me :/ even in Internet Explorer (WTF)

Comment: Please try Removing display:inline-block from .photo-matte

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a weird bug of Chrome. I can offer you to use `vh` instead of `%` in the padding property. I hope it'll give you a similar result.

Also I removed ".photo-inset" block and set borders directly for image.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.photo-frame {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5vh solid #000;
  background-color: #111;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.photo-matte {
  display: block;
  padding: 5vh 6vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 12px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
img {
  height: 70vh;
  display: block;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  border-top-color: rgba(170, 170, 170, 1.0);
  border-right-color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 1.0);
  border-bottom-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1.0);
  border-left-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1.0);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="photo-frame">
    <div class="photo-matte">
      <img src="http://jlee.me/glow_cube.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This one seems to work and render fine, but I've since gone with some different layout mechanics. I'm thinking it may have been some rendering quick with mixing % and viewport sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this fixed your issue, change:

```
.photo-matte {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

to:

```
.photo-matte {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display: inline-block;` in `display: inline-block;`

Or you can try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` for both `photo-matte` and `photo-frame`

---

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
/*background-color: #000;*/
}

.photo-frame {
display: inline-block;
/*padding: 30px;*/
padding: 1.75%;
background-color: #111;
/*background-color: rgb(47, 21, 17);*/

box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.photo-matte, .photo-frame{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.photo-matte {
display: inline-block;
padding: 5% 6%;
/*padding: 50px 60px;*/

background-color: #fff;
box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 12px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6), inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.photo-inset {
display: inline-block;
border: solid 5px #000;
border-top-color: rgba(170,170,170,1.0);
border-right-color: rgba(216,216,216,1.0);
border-bottom-color: rgba(240,240,240,1.0);
border-left-color: rgba(204,204,204,1.0);

/*box-shadow: 0px 0px 225px -30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);*/
}

img {
height: 70vh;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-frame">
  <div class="photo-matte">
   <div class="photo-inset">
    <img src="http://jlee.me/glow_cube.jpg"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This seems to work in codepen, but when I try it on a bare page it's the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Remove display property from class .photo-matte.
please try this:

```
.photo-matte {
   display:inline-block //remove this one
}
```

Comment: Strange. It seems to fix the issue when I run it in codepen, but on a bare HTML page it still renders incorrectly.

Comment: can you share the link of that?

Comment: Can you please tell me here the issue. I see nothing when i open in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `.photo-matte` class to match the following code:

```
.photo-matte {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:35px;
  background-color:#fff;
  box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 12px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6), inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  display:inline-block;
}
```